# How to detect and remove ringback-tone and ivrs voice etc from the beginning of an audio call recording

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, tone-generation

In an audio recording (say a telephone conv. b/w two people), how would I programatically detect and remove the dial-tone at the beginning of a call using python.
Ex : [image: sample audio call]
As you can see the first 15 seconds or so is just a dial tone like `tring-tring-tring-tring`.

Are there any audio analysis libraries in python that could  help me achieve this?

If this is not the right forum, kindly point me to the right place.

Comment: unless your country's telephones work extremely different then my country's ones, then "tring" is not a dial tone, but a ring tone? Also, what about simply detecting the crossing of an amplitude threshold? This looks extremely much like "amplitude higher than 0.7 for more than a millisecond" is a reliable detector.

Comment: Ok  thank you for correcting me. 
ringtone/hold music/ivrs was what I meant. the tring tring part. could you please point me to any python libraries please. thank you.

Comment: . OK, updating my question. But you got it right, I just want to `detect parts of the call which has automated IVRS, or hold music or the tring tring

Comment: @MarcusMüller Could you pleae tell me how to go about `"amplitude higher than 0.7 for more than a millisecond` detection method

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know where to start if you don't know what "amplitude" means in the context of a digital signal.

Comment: Sir, I know amplitude is height of a point on the Y axis with time on X axis. If possible could you please post your suggested solution about amplitude as an answer,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa) and [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html) to create a machine learning classifier. It would work roughly like this:

### Training

1. Get training signals of (A) just phone ringing, and (B) no phone ringing, e.g. ordinary conversation.
2. Segment the training signals with a frame size of ~50-500 milliseconds.
3. Extract features from each frame, e.g. MFCCs.
4. Train a scikit-learn classifier, e.g.

   ```
   classifier.fit(X, y)
   ```

   where `X` is a `ndarray` of feature vectors, and `y` are the target labels, e.g. "ring" (1) and "no ring" (0).

### Prediction

```
classifier.predict(X)
```

where `X` is an `ndarray` of feature vectors extracted in the same way from a test signal.

The latest frame which returns a positive "ring" label is where to truncate the signal.

Comment: by `Segment the training signals with a frame size of ~50-500 milliseconds` do you mean splitting the whole audio into pieces of 50milliseconds each? Or do you mean for it to be the sliding window frame size.

Comment: Do you have example for such sets to train and observe the results?